# Why can't I import DLL library in C++?

Tags: c++, dll, mingw, static-linking

I'm trying to load dynamic libraries in C++ with following codes

```cpp
Handle = LoadLibrary(wstring2string(FullLibraryPath).c_str());
```

In the terminal of CLion, it was fine. The same to Git Bash.
But when I am testing in `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe`.
The problem happened.

`LoadLibrary()` function returned a `NULL` value.
The error message is `The specified module could not be found.`

I thought it may be a problem with dynamic linking, so I tried to add `-static -lpthread` in the compile arguments.The CMakeList file just like

```
if (CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Windows")
    add_definitions("--static -lpthread -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
endif ()

add_library(io SHARED libio/library.cpp ${SRC_FILES})
add_library(string SHARED libstring/library.cpp ${SRC_FILES})
add_library(array SHARED libarray/library.cpp ${SRC_FILES})
add_library(thread SHARED libthread/library.cpp ${SRC_FILES})
add_library(fs SHARED libfs/library.cpp ${SRC_FILES})
add_library(sys SHARED libsys/library.cpp ${SRC_FILES})
```

Unfortunately, the problem still exists.

What's the cause of the problem? And, how can I fix it?

I've uploaded a example to my netdisk.
[link](http://www.xiaokang00010.top:11451/s/3XUl)

Thanks for Remy Lebeau's help. I've solve this problem with

```
if (CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Windows")
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
endif ()
```

Just add it before `add_library` or `add_executable` in the CMakeFileLists of  dynamic library.

Comment: You should take a look at the FullLibraryPath directory where the libraries are supposed to be.

Comment: I checked the directory and I put all the required dll files into this path. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Use `GetLastError()` to check error code.

Comment: The error code is 126. And I've said the error message in the description. 

```
The error message is The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Assuming `FullLibraryPath` is accurate (BTW, consider using `LoadLibraryW()` so you don't have to convert to `string`) and the DLL file actually exists, then the most likely culprit is the DLL is statically linked to another DLL that is not being found on the [search path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order). Use a tool like [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what file is actually being searched for that is not being found.

Comment: Here is a example, I uploaded it to my netdisk. [link](http://www.xiaokang00010.top:11451/s/3XUl)

Comment: Well, I tried to use Process Monitor to check DLLs. I noticed that the test program tried  to load `libwinpthread-1.dll` `libstdc++-6.dll` and `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`. On Git Bash, it can load from the directory of mingw compiler. On Powershell, it can't load from mingw  due to I didn't set up the env variable `PATH` for mingw. So, how to compile a static-linked DLL or exe file with cmake? Thanks for your reply.